# Java login screen how to read and save to local database

Tags: java, swing, authentication, jframe

Hi i am trying to make a `GUI login screen` that can read and save passwords(plain text is fine i dont need encryption) and usernames.
But i am not sure how to do that so far i have this. 
I would prefer for them to be stored in a local file not mysql but that would be ok.

[image]

```
package com.edu4java.swing.tutrial4;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class LoginView3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login");
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        placeComponents(frame);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void placeComponents(JFrame frame) {
        frame.setLayout(null);

        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User");
        userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
        frame.add(userLabel);

        JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
        frame.add(userText);

        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
        frame.add(passwordLabel);

        JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
        passwordText.setBounds(100, 40, 160, 25);
        frame.add(passwordText);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("login");
        loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        frame.add(loginButton);

        JButton registerButton = new JButton("register");
        registerButton.setBounds(180, 80, 80, 25);
        frame.add(registerButton);

        ActionListener loginButtonListener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(source, source.getText()
                        + " button has been pressed");
            }
        };
        loginButton.addActionListener(loginButtonListener);

        registerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) e.getSource(),
                        "button has been pressed");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

.

```
package com.edu4java.swing.tutrial4;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(source, source.getText() + " button has been pressed");
    }
}
```

.

```
package com.edu4java.swing.tutrial4;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LoginButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "login button has been pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: its good to narrow down your problem..

Comment: What you have done is just UI part. You have to write db access part

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Answer (score 0):

Well do you already have the database?
If not then I would recommend the MySQL Workbench to create it.

After that you can access your database with the jdbc-mysql driver. Java also offers a pretty cool technology called Java Persistence API (JPA) which makes the access to a database with more tables way easier than doing it the "common way".

Comment: Instead of a database a file would be better for my needs

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code. you have LoginButtonListener and MyButtonListener which is not being used in LoginView3.

also if you need to write to a file, what is the structure of the file (i.e. comma separated, tab separated etc).

at this point its an IO question and Not a UI question.

if you need to store user/password in a Line (comma separated).
then use FileOutPutStream and you can write the String with user/password in a line.

ex:

```
File file= new File("users.txt");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

bw.write(userText.getText()+","+new String(passwordText.getPassword()));
bw.newLine();

bw.close();
```

Comment: whatever method is best/easiest

Comment: sorry im new to java. I get 4 errors file, fileOutputStream , bufered writer and Output stream writer can not be resolved to a type

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1zf6pkmu3rc1kr/Untitled-1.png?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1zf6pkmu3rc1kr/Untitled-1.png?dl=0)

Comment: you need to import java.io package which contains these classes.